# Transforming parametric representation of coordinates into cartesian coordinate system

Tags: output-formatting

Is it possible in Wolfram Mathematica to transform output of BSplineFunction so it returns results in cartesian coordinates not in parametric representation?

---

Thank you for your responce.
I should have clarified the question better.

The question is: can I find coordinates that corespond to a given value of function.

For example, I have F(x,y,z,k). Let's say that substitution of several points such as

(x1,y1,z1,k1),(x2,y2,z2,k2),(x3,y3,z3,k3),...,(xn,yn,zn,kn)

gives the same value of fucntion F: F(x1,y1,z1,k1)=F(x2,y2,z2,k2)=...=F(xn,yn,zn,kn).
I need to know all these points (x1,y1,z1,k1)... in cartesian coordinate system.

Comment: A `BSplineFunction`isn't a `function` of `x`. (It's generally multivalued as such)

Comment: Mary, you should edit your Question with any additional details that are required, rather than posting Answers.  There is an "edit" link below your post and above these comments.

Answer (score 1):

No idea how you can deal with four-variable functions...
For a three-variable `BSplineFunction`, one way to see the points that satisfy `f[x,y,z]== w` is to use `ContourPlot3D`:

```
data = RandomReal[1, {5, 5, 5, 1}];
f = BSplineFunction[data];

ContourPlot3D[f[x, y, z], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}, 
 Contours -> {.4, .6},
 ImageSize -> 500, Mesh -> None, 
 PlotLabel -> Style["f[x,y,z] == " <> ToString[{.4, .6}], 20], 
 ContourStyle -> 
  Table[Directive[Hue[RandomReal[]], Opacity[0.8], 
    Specularity[White, 30]], {2}], PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

```
Row[ContourPlot3D[f[x, y, z] == #, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1},
ImageSize -> 300, Mesh -> None, 
PlotLabel -> Style["f[x,y,z] == " <> ToString[#], 20], 
ContourStyle -> 
 Directive[Hue[RandomReal[]], Opacity[0.8], 
  Specularity[White, 30]]] & /@ {.4, .5, .6}]
```

[image]